# Python 3.7 Flask-SocketIO + uWSGI + nginx configuration

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I'm hosting two python applications (app1 and app2) on ubuntu machine (16.04) under the same setup with different python versions (2.7 and 3.7), both are based on Flask framework using Flask-SocketIO, running on uWSGI (2.0.17.1) behind Nginx proxy.
I've been able to successfully implement websocket support in version 2.7 but im failing to do the same on 3.7.
Nginx configuration and uwsgi are the same, with only exception of different plugin for uwsgi (python version)
In both cases I'm using uwsgi websocket server (via SocketIO) with redis queue.
Beside websocket problem app2 works just fine.

## Python Setup

**Python 2.7 Libs:**

Flask==0.12.2

Flask-SocketIO==2.9.4

gevent==1.2.2

greenlet==0.4.13

**Python 3.7 Libs:**

Flask==1.0.2

Flask-Script==2.0.6

gevent==1.3.7

greenlet==0.4.15

**uWSGI** - 2.0.17.1

## Working configuration of app1:

#### __init__.py

```
  app = Flask(__name__)
    # SocketIO
    try:  # This step is required only for version deployed on UWSGI
        import uwsgi
        socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=app.config['REDIS_QUEUE_URL'])
    except ImportError:
        print 'Application runs outside of uWSGI context'
        socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

#### manage.py

```
from flask-script import Manager
from app1 import app

@manager.command
def runserver(host = None, port = None, socket = True):
    if not host:
        host = 'localhost'
    if not port:
        port = 5000
    if socket:
        socketio.run(app)
    else:
        app.run(host, port, debug=False)
```

#### app1.ini

```
  [uwsgi]
    plugins-dir = /usr/local/lib/uwsgi
    plugins = python27
    #application's base folder
    base = /home/ubuntu/app1

    #python module to import
    app = manage
    module = %(app)

    home = %(base)/venv
    virtualenv = %(base)/venv
    pythonpath = %(base)

    #socket file's location
    socket = %(base)/app1.sock

    #permissions for the socket file
    chmod-socket = 666

    callable = app

    logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

    processes = 20

    http-websockets = true

    gevent = 500

    vacuum = true

    die-on-term = true

    enable-threads = true

    master = true
```

#### app1-site

```
server {
    listen 1014 ssl default_server;
    server_name server_name_1;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app1_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app1_error_log;
    auth_basic off;
    # SSL only
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

location /socket.io/ {
    include uwsgi_params;             
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app1/app1.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}

location / {deny all;}
location = /app1{ rewrite ^ /app1/; }
location /app1{
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_redirect      http://server:8080 https://server_name_1:1014/app1;
        try_files $uri @app1; }

location @app1{
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app1;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 180s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app1/app1.sock;
}}
```

## Configuration of app2

### __init__.py

```
 def create_app():
        ...
        app = Flask(__name__)
        socket_io.init_app(app, message_queue = app.config['REDIS_URL'])
        ...
        return app
```

### wsgi.py

```
 import uwsgi
    from gevent.monkey import patch_all

    patch_all()
    print('Patching all!')

    from app2 import create_app

    application = create_app()
```

### app2.ini

```
[uwsgi]
plugins-dir = /usr/local/lib/uwsgi
plugins = python37

#application's base folder
base = /home/ubuntu/app2

home = %(base)/venv
virtualenv = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

mount = /app2=%(base)/wsgi.py

callable = application

socket = %(base)/app2.sock

chmod-socket = 666

chdir = %(base)
attach-daemon = %(virtualenv)/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker
attach-daemon = %(virtualenv)/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery beat

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

processes = 20

vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

enable-threads = true

master = true

manage-script-name = true

http-websockets = true

gevent = 5000

#Workaround for flask send_file() failing on python 3 and uwsgi
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true
```

### app2-site

```
  server {
        listen 1015 ssl default_server;
        server_name server_name_2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/app2_access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/app2_error_log;


        auth_basic off;

        # SSL only
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location /socket.io/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_buffering off;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app2/app2.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 180s;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    } 

    location / {deny all;}
    location = /app2 { rewrite ^ /app2/; }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://server_name_2:1015/app2;
        try_files $uri @app2; }

    location @app2 {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 180s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 180s;
        proxy_read_timeout 180s;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app2/app2.sock;
    }}
```

Based on my research problem is in uWSGI, for some reason it is not receiving any wss calls. From client perspective socket connection is **Finished** instead of **101 Pending**.

Issue persist no matter of what client I'm using.

In app1 I can see each attemp&error of socket connection in both nginx and uwsgi (vassal) log files, in case of app2 I can only see 499 error for each socket connection attempt, without matching entry in vassal log.

Initially I was blaming uwsgi websocket server, that could host only 1 application, but I can freely duplicate app1 as many times as I want under different vassals and nginx sites, websocket connections are fine.

## What I've tried

- switching between lib versions (gevent must be >= 1.3.6)
- using http socket instead of unix one
- experiments with paths
- juggling with buffer sizes on both nginx and uwsgi

Are there any known issues with python 3.7 & uwsgi & SocketIO integration? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have never tried uWSGI on Python 3.7, but I had success using Socket.IO apps with 3.6. The 499 status code is from nginx, and it means the client closed the request (see https://httpstatuses.com/499). Not sure if nginx reuses the 499 status code for other error conditions, so far I have found no references on that.

Comment: I cannot fully agree on that. Nginx tends to throw 499 in both scenarios - when client broke connection and when uwsgi didnt manag to reply. So broken pipe on either end. Could you share your 3.6 setup configuration? That might give me some hint.

Comment: My working uWSGI and nginx setups appear in the documentation. Start here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#uwsgi-web-server

Comment: the only difference here is using http socket instead of unix one. I've checked that already, with no effect.